# ToggleGroup to toggle between male and female java

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a toggle button that changes the selected gender, I am trying to get it to toggle between male and female but when I run it and select a group, it doesn't select either one.

```
    ToggleGroup genderToggle = new ToggleGroup();
    maleButton.setToggleGroup(genderToggle); 
    maleButton.setUserData("male");
    femaleButton.setToggleGroup(genderToggle); 
    femaleButton.setUserData("female");
    submitButton.setOnAction(new ButtonListener());
    genderToggle.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>()  
    { 
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ob, Toggle o, Toggle n) 
        {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)genderToggle.getSelectedToggle(); 

        if (genderToggle.equals("male"))
        {
            maleButton.setSelected(true);
            femaleButton.setSelected(false);
        }
        else if (genderToggle.equals("female"))
        {
            maleButton.setSelected(false);
            femaleButton.setSelected(true);
        }
        else
        {
            maleButton.setSelected(false);
            femaleButton.setSelected(false);
        }
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Can u include a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's best to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem. You should also include what library you're using (which, based on some of the method and class names, I assume is JavaFX?).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are using `.equals(...)` on the toggle object, instead first get the user data field, as this is the one you set to the gender string. E.g.:

```
if (genderToggle.getUserData().equals("female"))
   {
      maleButton.setSelected(false);
      femaleButton.setSelected(true);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I have a getGender and setGender method in a "grandparent" class that only allows gender to be "male" or "female", how do I go about validating that the data from this class equals the super class?

Comment: @Extrinsik eh is that part of the original question? I don't get what u mean, do u want to compare the fields of two objects that have the same super class? Because in that case just use getters, or make the fields protected. If u want to override the method in the super class, and compare it to what if would have returned in the unaltered super class version, u can call `super.getField()' inside the class extending the parent class.

Comment: Originally the button didnt work, and with your help I was able to get it to work, but then I wanted to compare the values with the super class to see if "male" or "female" was a valid option before proceeding so that I did not have to create new methods in the class I am currently working in. With your help and a little bit of research I was able to figure it out and apply it to the rest of my code. Thank you for taking the time to assist me.